# Android Textview Wraps and ugly formatting

Tags: android

I have created a android textview field .My problem is i want all text to come to new line as soon as there is a Enter or "/n" on the line .For Example :-
I have a text line below :-

```
 Twinkle, twinkle, little star,How I wonder what you are.
 Up above the world so high,Like a diamond in the sky.
```

I want this to come as shown below but when i use the below code it wraps the lines during runtime .Any Idea how can i do this .My Code is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DisplayGanMessageActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_display_gan_message" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="
 Twinkle, twinkle, little star,How I wonder what you are.
 Up above the world so high,Like a diamond in the sky."/>
```

I got the below output from this :- 
Twinkle, twinkle, little star,How I wonder what you are.Up above the world so high,Like a diamond in the sky

Comment: I got the below output from this :-

Twinkle, twinkle, little star,How I wonder what you are.Up above the world so high,Like a diamond in the sky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Twinkle, twinkle, little star,How I wonder what you are. \n Up above the world so high,Like a diamond in the sky."/>
```

Comment: Might want to change it to \n for the new line